# How do I get a message box in Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

```
>>> from Tkinter import tkMessageBox

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from Tkinter import tkMessageBox
ImportError: cannot import name tkMessageBox
```

I am getting this error, even though `from Tkinter import *` is working fine. I am using Python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`tkMessageBox` is a module on its own, so you should import it separately:

```
import Tkinter 
import tkMessageBox
```